# Sample Users for Activiti Database

Tags: activiti

I am completely new to Activiti. I have downloaded the activiti setup and managed to run the sample WAR files in tomcat. I am using Activiti in action. I have the following confusions in mind.

1. I was using sample application deployed. It has built in users and processes support. Though following activiti in action, i can't see the process used by kermit in his inbox. Because of this, i created my own oracle schema for activiti. How can import these existing user roles, groups and data into my own database? Is it possible? I just want to see it working at database levels.
2. Any sample case studies for activiti at the beginner level. I have seen some examples but not a full fledge beginner case study.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the answer from activiti user guide. Activiti comes bundled with activiti-explorer.war.
Here are the steps for the demo data.

1. Activiti comes bundled with database scripts, compatible with different databases. I was using oracle so, i created a schema called activiti. I ran the scripts compatible with oracle from activiti bundle.
2. The war file contains file activiti-standalone-context.xml, following properties should be enabled.

> ```
> <bean id="demoDataGenerator" class="org.activiti.explorer.demo.DemoDataGenerator">
>         <property name="processEngine" ref="processEngine" />
>         <property name="createDemoUsersAndGroups" value="false" />
>         <property name="createDemoProcessDefinitions" value="false" />
>         <property name="createDemoModels" value="false" />
>  </bean>
> ```

1. Open the file db.properties present in WEB-INF/classes folder of the archive and change the database settings to point to your database. Here is what my configuration looks like.

> db=xe jdbc.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
>   jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe jdbc.username=activiti
>   jdbc.password=activiti

Modify these settings and re-add to the activiti-explorer.war archive. Re-start your tomcat and you are good to go with the demo data.

Ben